# Pandas groupby to json and nested it under the name of the group

Tags: python, json, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this Dataframe:

```
$ df 
    EU S.   A.  B.  C.  
    Ar 63   7   8   0
    Az 51   8   12  7
    Be 95   15  4   5
    Ge 81   8   5   5
    Ka 61   3   7   4
```

When I grouped it by "EU:

```
df.groupby(by="EU").sum().to_json(orient="index")
```

I am getting:

```
    {
        Ar:{
               S.: 63, A.: 7, B.: 8, C.: 0
           },{
        Az:{
               S.: 51, A.: 8, B.: 12, C.: 7
           },{
               Be:{S.: 95, A.: 15, B.: 5, C.: 5} ...
    }
```

What I really want is:

```
{
  EU:{
        Ar:{
               S.: 63, A.: 7, B.: 8, C.: 0
           },{
        Az:{
               S.: 51, A.: 8, B.: 12, C.: 7
           },{
               Be:{S.: 95, A.: 15, B.: 5, C.: 5} ...
     }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to handle this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a nested dictionary with top level key as the group name then use `json.dumps` to serialize this dict as `json` formatted `str`.

```
import json

j = json.dumps({'EU': df.groupby('EU').sum().to_dict('i')})
```

---

```
{
    "EU": {
        "Ar": {
            "S.": 63,
            "A.": 7,
            "B.": 8,
            "C.": 0
        },
        ...
        ...
        "Ka": {
            "S.": 61,
            "A.": 3,
            "B.": 7,
            "C.": 4
        }
    }
}
```